# Jr. Sys Admin mistake, Can/Do I need to Un-RAID 0 my drives?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, ssd

Backstory: Just started as a Jr. Sys Admin, Cleaning up data center, re-purposing workstations I find to update currently used workstations.

I started off with a terminal that had some potential, i7-4790, 8 GB Ram, but only had 1 120GB SSD with Windows 7 pro. I found a 4TB NAS HDD and figured I could just throw that in the system and I'd have a nice little workstation. On boot-up, the system didn't show the HDD anywhere. Except when I opened Intel Rapid Storage Technology app. I saw both drives and it said I could link them in an Array. In hind-sight I should have researched the outcome of this a bit. But, I jumped right in and followed the extremely easy to use wizard. Unfortunately when I rebooted the system and look at my C: drive I still only see 1 drive with 50Gb free of 107GB, but in my device manager I see an Intel Raid 0 with a capacity of 244GB and 122GB of unallocated space. Did I just squander the remaining 3.7 TB? Can I un-raid these, or is there a way to partitian the remaining space into a regular drive?

Comment: I always avoid that fakeraid crap. Turn it off, set the SATA mode to AHCI, and forget it exists, unless you want to be haunted by nightmares for the rest of your career...

Comment: Heh Michael, that's pretty much the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the disks from the array first. Take an image of the current volume and restore that once you've finished disassembling the world's silliest RAID array (not mocking you, but this question did bring some joy to my day).